# Display HTML in the FullCalender title prop / events

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using FullCalender (V 6.1.6). I want to add a html button inside the calender. I have not found any way to write the same in the documentation.

{ title: 'Details', start: '2023-04-16', allDay: true}

I have try this, but it is a json object which converts into the Event. Event the title prop is not supported HTML. If I try the write the HTML in the title prop, it prints the html as a text.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks